# Implement Google SSO in custom plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I have this code that is used for the callback of a custom route

```php
    public function login_user_with_google( WP_REST_Request $request )
    {
        $client = new Google\Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig( CREDENTIALS );
        //$client->addScope(Google\Service\Calendar::CALENDAR);
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts");
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms");
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail");
        // Your redirect URI can be any registered URI, but in this example
        // we redirect back to this same page
        $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        //
        $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
        //
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        //
        //header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); 
        //
        if( isset( $_GET['code'] ) ){
            //
            $_SESSION['code_verifier'] = $client->getOAuth2Service()->generateCodeVerifier();
            //
            $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode( $_GET['code'], $_SESSION['code_verifier']);
            //
            $client->setAccessToken($token);
            // store in the session also
            $_SESSION['google_token'] = $token;
            // redirect back to the example
            //header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));            
        }

        // set the access token as part of the client
        //if( !empty( $_SESSION['upload_token'] ) ){
        //    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['google_token']);
        //    if( $client->isAccessTokenExpired() ){
        //        unset($_SESSION['google_token']);
        //    }
        //} else {
        //    $_SESSION['code_verifier'] = $client->getOAuth2Service()->generateCodeVerifier();
        //    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        //    return $authUrl;
        //}

    }
```

I need to get a token to use some google workspace functions and I've implemented the Google php client library, I'm testing the route but at the moment I'm unable to achive my scope, do I need to modify the code?

Comment: What do you mean 'achieve the scope'? Get access to the logged in user's calendar? Or is one of the client calls failing?

Comment: I need to get access to google calandar, contacts and gmail. I've tested some plugins but unfortunately they will not give me the needed token and scopes

Comment: note that by using `$_SESSION` your code will not work on a lot of managed WordPress hosts, and you aren't avoiding the use of cookies either as it requires a cookie to track which sessions values to use. Your title also asks how to implement SSO, but your question text talks about using calendar/mail APIs rather than logging people in

Comment: @TomJNowell due to the Google api, it's impossible to use worksapce api if people are not logged. this is why I need the SSO process. at the moment I'm not on a managed wordpress hosting but on a traditional hosting service where I've installed wordpress manually so I don't think I will have problems

Comment: I understand that, you need a logged in google user to connect to the API, but your question title mentions single sign on, which is a very different thing, aka how do I let users sign on to my site using google? Which is not what you're asking about judging from your comment. You should update your title accordingly to mention authenticate with google rather than SSO as it's highly misleading. Note that I mention managed hosts because they're a good example, lots of shared hosts and others disable them too with lots of good reasons from security to memory footprints

Comment: in the meantime, what you're written implies that your endpoint works and creates an API connection, but the authenticated connection it negotiates lacks the API scopes you desire. If that's the case then this isn't a WordPress problem and no amount of WP knowledge will be able to assist here, instead you need Google SDK help and might be better asking on stackoverflow, that it's being done in a REST API endpoint is coincidental. Include details of how you're testing that it has the scope you desired

Comment: ( btw if its a REST API endpoint why query `$_GET` directly instead of `$request`? `login_user_with_google` is also a bit misleading, connect would be a better word than login, you have a high risk of being misinterpreted as trying to create WP user sessions using Google as an SSO provider. You could also have saved those tokens in user meta instead of PHP sessions which would be more secure/reliable and allow keeping a session across browsers and devices